# Select query to joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tableone: id | userid | date | photo | caption | visible
tabletwo: id | userid | date | text  | gender  | notes
```

I have two tables with different columns. I want to select rows from both using a single query, I would do the do this using the date (timestamp) and userid. Is it possible to join them together?

```
SELECT id, photo, caption, visible
FROM `tableone`
WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` = '$d'
ORDER BY date desc

SELECT id, text, gender, notes
FROM `tabletwo`
WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` = '$d'
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 1
```

EDIT: Desired output:

```
(
    [id] => 3
    [photo] => 1
    [caption] => Sample text
    [visible] => 1
    [text] => 
    [gender] => 
    [notes] => 
)
(
    [id] => 23
    [photo] => 1
    [caption] => More sample text
    [visible] => 
    [text] => 
    [gender] => 
    [notes] => 
)
(
    [id] => 1
    [photo] => 
    [caption] => 
    [visible] => 
    [text] => Blah jaspidj
    [gender] => 2
    [notes] => Sample Text
)
```

Comment: this question seems to get asked almost every day.

Comment: look into SQL JOIN keyword.

Comment: I'm not wanting to join the columns together. I'm wanting to merge the two tables, but keep the rows separate.

Comment: Please show example expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is [`UNION`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) (see [MySql UNION reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)), which combines the results of two queries together. Typically you only union results that have the same columns, however you are asking for two different types of queries to be unioned. If all you care about is seeing all results together and you don't care about having blank cells, then this should work for you:

```
(SELECT id, photo, caption, visible, null AS text, null AS gender, null AS notes
FROM `tableone`
WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` = '$d'
ORDER BY date desc)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, null AS photo, null AS caption, null AS visible, text, gender, notes
FROM `tabletwo`
WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` = '$d'
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 1)
```

*(Note that I used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, which basically means "give me all results, including duplicates". Since there could not be duplicates in this set, it is safe to use `UNION ALL` to get a performance boost)*

The output of this doesn't logically make sense, but it should give you the example output you showed above.

Comment: In this case, you would want to use UNION ALL which is faster as the two statements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there anyway to have the LIMIT 1 only apply to  tabletwo? I had to remove it because it was limiting the whole query to 1.

Comment: Yes, place the individual queries in parentheses. I'll update my answer to reflect this. See the [mysql union page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

So you can get both table rows data having userid and date like param?
Ok so will have to use a JOIN to get them all in one row

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.userid, t1.date, t1.photo, t1.caption, t1.visible, t2.text, t2.gender, t2.notes
FROM tableone t1 JOIN tableone t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.userid = "yourwantedid" AND t1.date = "yourwanteddate"
```

You can use just the table 1 in the WHERE clause because you will join both tables in one.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope this help

I recently see your comment, may be you want to use the UNION ALL clause

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.userid, t1.date, t1.photo, t1.caption, t1.visible
FROM tableone t1
WHERE userid = "yourwantedid" AND date = "yourwanteddate"
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.userid, t2.date, t2.text as photo, t2.gender as caption, t2.notes as visible
FROM tabletwo t2
WHERE userid = "yourwantedid" AND date = "yourwanteddate"
```

you have to put an alias on the columns to use the UNION ALL clause, which match the columns names of both selects.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope this help

Comment: You have a handful of errors in your `UNION ALL` example. You're using the alias `t1` though it hasn't been defined, you're referencing columns that don't exist in `tableone`, and you're selecting from `tableone` twice.

Comment: You were right, i edit my resolve because of his recently comment, and i did it worng. I edit it now. Thanks!!